# Flow type annotation for Array of one type or another (but not both)

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

I have a function that can take an Array of numbers or an Array of strings (but not an Array of numbers and strings).

In other words, the Array might resemble `[1, 2, 3]` OR `['1', '2', '3']`

but NOT `[1, '2', 3]`

Right now I declare it like so

`function fn<T>(options: Array<T>): Array<T> { ... }`

but this ^ would allow for Array of any single type (strings, numbers, objects, whatever).

Looking at the [docs on Flow's generic types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/), the only alternative I can think of looks like this

`function fn<T: string | number>(options: Array<T>): Array<T> { ... }`

but that ^ allows for an Array that contains both strings and numbers, which as explained above, is not what I want...

Surely, there's a way to flow type an Array of strings OR an Array of numbers...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Array<string> | Array<number>
```

Which reads as *an array of strings or an array of numbers*

Comment: Doh! Thanks! For some reason I was convinced I needed to use generics...

Comment: @sfletche glad to help :)

Comment: why does javascript starting to look more and more like java !!

Comment: @alexander this is typescript not javascript, and its still much cooler than java.